# How to invalidate items cached using an OutputCacheProvider in WCF Data Service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, caching, .net-4.0

I have an implementation of data caching in a wcf data service that follows this; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peter_qian/archive/2010/11/17/using-asp-net-output-caching-with-wcf-data-services.aspx

Toward the end of the article it suggets that you can implement your own custom cache provider by extending OutputCacheProvider. I have done this and tested the cache works fine.

I cannot however, get the output cache to work with a data cache dependency as outlined in the above article. As soon as a add in the line;

```
            context.Response.AddCacheItemDependency(cacheDependencyItemKey);
```

I get the following error;

*When using a custom output cache provider like 'DiskOutputCache', only the following expiration policies and cache features are supported:  file dependencies, absolute expirations, static validation callbacks and static substitution callbacks.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: When using a custom output cache provider like 'DiskOutputCache', only the following expiration policies and cache features are supported:  file dependencies, absolute expirations, static validation callbacks and static substitution callbacks.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ProviderException: When using a custom output cache provider like 'DiskOutputCache', only the following expiration policies and cache features are supported:  file dependencies, absolute expirations, static validation callbacks and static substitution callbacks.]
   System.Web.Caching.OutputCache.InsertResponse(String cachedVaryKey, CachedVary cachedVary, String rawResponseKey, CachedRawResponse rawResponse, CacheDependency dependencies, DateTime absExp, TimeSpan slidingExp) +2905959
   System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +107
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75***

```
    protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
    {
        base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context.Cache.Get(cacheDependencyItemKey) == null) {
            // what the cache item value is doesn't really matter 
            context.Cache.Insert(cacheDependencyItemKey, "Item");
        }

        if (context.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            context.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("MERGE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            context.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("PUT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            context.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("DELETE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            context.Cache.Remove(cacheDependencyItemKey);

        } else {
            // set cache policy to this page 
            HttpCachePolicy cachePolicy = context.Response.Cache;

            // server&private: server and client side cache only 
            cachePolicy.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate);

            // default cache expire: never 
            cachePolicy.SetExpires(DateTime.MaxValue);

            // cached output depends on: accept, charset, encoding, and all parameters (like $filter, etc) 
            cachePolicy.VaryByHeaders["Accept"] = true;
            cachePolicy.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Charset"] = true;
            cachePolicy.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
            cachePolicy.VaryByParams["*"] = true;

            cachePolicy.SetValidUntilExpires(true);

            // add data cache dependency 
            context.Response.AddCacheItemDependency(cacheDependencyItemKey);
        }
    }
```

This error would seems to suggest that you cannot use a CacheItemDependency in WCF like this. I'm confused as it appears to work in the msdn blog article.

Any thoughts?

**Batch updates appear to be problematic**

In data services when you are using the *DataServiceContext* and excute     *SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);* the request uri looks like "~/$batch" so there doesn't appear to be an easy way to actually determine what is being created, updated or deleted in attempt to invalidate those items.

I am assuming in the logic block below for changes to the web service data you would have to call a remove directly on the cache, and have the underyling cache provider work out what needs to be removed. But there doesn't seem to be an easy way to actually determine what has changed. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this needs to be done within your custom OutputCacheProvider. According to the article: "Note that if you go this route, then you cannot add output page dependencies to data cache items. You’ll have to implement the dependency logic inside your provider."

Comment: I totally missed that note. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll take a look and see if this solves my problem and get back to you. The problem with data services is its not easy to tell what item or items are being updated because the path often ends up like $batch if the items were saved or updated using the batch save. So I cannot really see how it is easy to remove just the item(s) that have changed, or even setup multiple 'groups' as suggested in the article. Clearing the entire cache on any item change is obviously not desirable either.

Comment: Joshua unfortunately I can't help with that bit as I'm not familiar with EF. In NHibernate I would probably create an interceptor that can examine the added/deleted/modified objects and simply have that interceptor notify the OutputCacheProvider but I'm not sure whether EF has similar hooks you could use.